# How to replace values of multiple columns with other columns within the same dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to update values of mulitple columns from other columns.

```
test <- data.frame(old1 = c(NA,NA,NA),
                   old2 = c(NA,NA,NA),
                   old3 = c(NA,NA,NA),
                 upd1 = c('1','2','3'),
                 upd2 = c('a','b','c'),
                 upd3 = c('I','II','III')
                 )
```

I want to update column `old1` with values of `upd1`, `old2` with `upd2` and so on. One method is to do one by one, e.g use `ifelse` inside `mutate(...)` for each column. But this is not ideal as the columns are over 100. I want something like this:

```
test %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = c(1:3),  ~replace(., is.na(.), c(upd1)) #this is wrong though.
                )
         )
```

This updates all columns with values of column `upd1` but it can't accept mutiple columns inside the replace or ifelse function. Perhaps for loop may work but I am pretty new and don't have the expertise with loops.

Another method is to split the dataframe into two and use `merge()` and then `aggregate()` function. But it changes the type of certain columns and changes values of date columns to other formats.

Any tidyverse solution, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `across2` from `dplyover`:

```r
library(dplyover)
test %>% 
  mutate(across2(starts_with("old"), starts_with("upd"),
                 ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), .y, .x), 
                 .names = "{xcol}"))

  old1 old2 old3 upd1 upd2 upd3
1    1    a    I    1    a    I
2    2    b   II    2    b   II
3    3    c  III    3    c  III
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr::cur_column` and `get` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

test %>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = starts_with("old"),
    ~ coalesce(.x, get(gsub("^old", "upd", cur_column())))
  ))
#>   old1 old2 old3 upd1 upd2 upd3
#> 1    1    a    I    1    a    I
#> 2    2    b   II    2    b   II
#> 3    3    c  III    3    c  III
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace()` works with multiple columns.  You can do:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(replace(across(starts_with("old")), TRUE, across(starts_with("up"))))

  old1 old2 old3 upd1 upd2 upd3
1    1    a    I    1    a    I
2    2    b   II    2    b   II
3    3    c  III    3    c  III
```

You could also use `modifyList()` if you rename the `up` set to match the `old` set:

```
test %>%
  mutate(modifyList(across(starts_with("old")), across(starts_with("up"), .names = "{sub('^upd', 'old', col)}")))

  old1 old2 old3 upd1 upd2 upd3
1    1    a    I    1    a    I
2    2    b   II    2    b   II
3    3    c  III    3    c  III
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('old'),
   ~ coalesce(.x, cur_data()[[str_replace(cur_column(), "ol", "up")]])))
```

-output

```
   old1 old2 old3 upd1 upd2 upd3
1    1    a    I    1    a    I
2    2    b   II    2    b   II
3    3    c  III    3    c  III
```